# Randomly picking a positions of a given value in the matrix and switching it to another given value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a given matrix

`M= np.array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],[7, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 7],[7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7],[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])`

I'm trying to randomly pick `k` values that are equal to `1` in the matrix and transform them to `5`.

So, let's say that `k=4` then the code would randomly pick 4 values in the matrix that are equal to 1 and switch them to 5. The matrix might then look like:

`M= np.array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],[7, 1, 5, 8, 1, 5, 7],[7, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 7],[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])`

But could also look like:

`M= np.array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],[7, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 7],[7, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 7],[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])`

I've been trying to use `np.where()` but I can't figure out the way to make the switch random and make it happen `k` times. Every time I was trying to make it work it was switching all the `1` values in the matrix.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. "I've been trying to use np.where()" - What specifically have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? If you can [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with your code, we can provide more specific help

Comment: `np.where(M==1,5,M)` So, this code changes all the values in the matrix that are equal to `1` into `5`. As I want random values of `1` I was trying to use different `random` commands like `random.choice()` within `np.where()` so for example `np.where(random.choice(M==1),5,M)` but as I learned it cannot be done this way.

Comment: @LSM - Please use the edit function to add informations to your question not a comment. Your approach is expedient, but not supported in the legacy module `np.random`.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended [random generator api](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) does support what you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],[7, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 7],[7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7],[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]]) 

rng = np.random.default_rng()
x,y = rng.choice(np.where(M == 1), size=4, replace=False, axis=1)
M[x,y] = 5
M
```

Output

```
array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 1, 1, 8, 5, 5, 7],
       [7, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use np.where to get the list of indices where the selected value exists, random.sample to get `k` indices from that list, and then use those indices to update the values. It's likely not the most efficient possible way, but it's the clearest, IMO

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample

M= np.array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],[7, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 7],[7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7],[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])

#Find indices 
m_ones=list(zip(*np.where(M==1)))

m_ones
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]

#Select k items from list of indices
samp=sample(m_ones,k=3)
samp
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1)]

#Loop through indices and update values
for i in samp:
    M[i]=5

M
array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 1, 1, 8, 5, 5, 7],
       [7, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])
```